# HTTP POST non standard JSON (MongoDB doc format)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a Mongo Admin UI where I'm trying to send a fully formed MongoDB document (eg: could contain ObjectId, ISODate elements) to an ExpessJS server in order to insert/update docs. The problem I'm facing is that due to the syntax not being standard JSON, bodyParser returns http code 400 - bad request when it does a JSON.parse().

Am I missing something really obvious? I've thought about sending the POST as plain text and then parsing it myself and creating an object on the ExpressJs side. I don't really want to roll my own custom JSON parser though. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Because, when you convert bson to json, bson deserializer adding type information to json. This can't be recognized by normal JSON parsers. You should use mongodb extended json parser.

> Strict mode. Strict mode representations of BSON types conform to the JSON RFC. Any JSON parser can parse these strict mode representations as key/value pairs; however, only the MongoDB internal JSON parser recognizes the type information conveyed by the format.

Check [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/).

Comment: I understand the BSON vs JSON but I'm still confused about how this data should be sent to my backend if it cannot pass the JSON.parse()? Is there a library that can convert to strict mode BSON before doing my HTTP POST to my backend?

Comment: It's not illegal json format **BSON types conform to the JSON RFC**. So you can pass it.

Comment: Im not sure they do. If I do a JSON.parse() it fails if there is ObjectID() or ISODate().

Comment: Ah this seems to be what I'm looking for. Thanks for getting me this far. Is there a library which can convert as per this document that you know of? : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/

Comment: I didn't use by myself but you can check this https://github.com/mongodb-js/extended-json

Comment: After reading further it looks like that project is strictly Node and won't work in the browser. It does give me enough clues that I might roll my own client side/browser version unless I find someone who has already done it.

Comment: @mrvautin, are you able to post a sample of your Jason dated that JSON.parse() could not parse?

Comment: @SO1 It was Mongodb specific stuff like: { "dt" : ISODate("2013-10-01T00:00:00.000Z") }